# Visual Studio 2015: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when creating Azure Mobile App

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-mobile-services

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. The error occours when I try to create an Azure Mobile App.

I go to *File* > *New* > *Project* > *ASP.NET Web Application*. Then I try to create an Azure Mobile App and get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. [See screenshot of error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNOAf.png)

Things I've already tried:

- Repairing Visual Studio, multiple times
- Deleting all user settings
- Reinstalling Android SDK API 19,20,21,22,23

Any idea how to fix this VS error?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also on Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with Azure SDK 2.9 (make sure you are using the latest and greatest Azure SDK).  This works for me, so it's definitely something with your visual studio version.

An alternative for you is to create a regular MVC app and add Mobile Apps SDK to it.  I wrote a blog post on this here:  https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/06/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-17-asp-net-backend-introduction/